# dynamic array auto shrink

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

When designing a dynamic array which will shrink, what is a method to keep track of the highest used index, and when that index's held object is deleted, **find the new highest used index**.

Right now I can think up having a a simple `int last_used` and then charging the cost of maintaining this variable to the `func_delete` which must check if it deletes the highest, and if so, check each smaller value looking for a non null. (array will always be null initialized)

```
if(last_index == deleted_index){

    while(last_index >0 && array[--last_index] != NULL)

    // if the array is now only half full, I realloc 
}
```

Is there any other smart ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks okay to me, but logic wise, if the function `func_delete` always deletes the highest item, then there shouldn't be any `NULL` values at smaller indices. So this should do:

```
if(last_index == deleted_index && array[last_index] != NULL) {
    //delete last item
    free(array[last_index]);
    //set to NULL and decrement
    array[last_index--] = NULL;
}
```

**Edit**:

based on your comments, I understand what you're trying to do, I think you could just keep track of the highest used index in the insertion function instead:

```
void array_insert(array , element e, int index) 
{
    if (index > arr->highest_index) {
       arr->highest_index = index;
    }
    //insert element
}
```

And when you delete you check if the index is the highest or not. like you're doing, don't think there's a better way to do that, without complicating things further, for example, you could keep another sorted list of indices, this way you when you delete the highest index you find the next one in constant time, but like I said, it complicates things. However, I think another data structure might be more useful, a linked list for example, is more efficient when randomly deleting nodes, but not when randomly inserting nodes.

Comment: The assumption that assumes is that all lower indices are filled. That is not the case in my scenario. There are runs of empty slots. Hence my initial idea of a linear search down.

Comment: @mattclemens that's really wrong, if you allow any index to be used then you should allow any index to be deleted, otherwise, how can I free an element in a lower index ?

Comment: I should make more clear that i'm not deleting the array's memory block, but merely the data object that it points to.

Comment: @mattclemens yes I understand that, but you seem to be missing my point, say I have a `100` elements array, then I fill the first and last elements, now I want to delete the first one ? I can't right ?

Comment: @mattclemens besides, that's not really a dynamic array, that's a fixed size array of pointers, a [dynamic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) array `grows`

Comment: I think my question was misworded, I think is clearly explains it now.

Comment: @mattclemens much better, but still, if you allow random insertions then you should allow random deletion, otherwise, make the insertion and deletion sequential.

Comment: I do allow random deletion, it's just I need to keep track of the highest used index so I can efficiently realloc an unnecessary large array. Say when it's only half utilized.